# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple javascript function for validating to fields in a aspx page

```
function validate()

{
 if (document.getElementById("<%=tbName.ClientID%>").value=="")
  {
             alert("Name Feild can not be blank");
             document.getElementById("<%=tbName.ClientID%>").focus();
             return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("<%=ddlBranch.ClientID%>").value=="SelectBranch")
  {
             alert("Branch Should Be Selected");
             document.getElementById("<%=ddlBranch.ClientID%>").focus();
             return false;
  }

}
```

Everything worked fine.
Later I linked it to aspx page like a external js file.

head runat="server">

script src="validation.js" type="text/javascript">

/script>

```
<title>Validations</title>
```

/head>

```
<form id="form" runat="server">



<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Nmae: ">/asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" Width="130px">/asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblBranch" runat="server" Text="Branch:">/asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBranch" runat="server" Width="107px">
        <asp:ListItem>CSE</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ECE</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>CIVIL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MECH</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="SelectBranch">SelectBranch</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>    
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validate(<%=tbName.ClientID%>, <%=ddlBranch.ClientID%>)" />

</form>
```

and

In aspx.cs page

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript", "<SCRIPT Language='JavaScript' src='validation.js'></SCRIPT>"); 
    btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return validate()");

}
```

Now its giving error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required".

I'm unable to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script can only run **inside** the aspx page as it is. `<%=tbName.ClientID%>` is server-side logic it's placing the literal client-side ID in the output to the client, so before it looked like this when rendered in the HTML:

```
document.getElementById("tbName")
//looks for <input id="tbName" />
```

Now it looks **just** like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=tbName.ClientID%>")
//looks for <input id="<%=tbName.ClientID%>" /> ... doesn't exist :)
```

Since it's no longer finding an object/element (because *that* ID doesn't exist) you're getting the `object required` error.  You have to either keep this logic in the page, or move to some other approach using classes, etc.  If you're doing a lot of validation, I'd take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [validation library](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

---

**Update:** Here's the solution [T.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) provided for you in comments in full text form for an easier read.  If you're only validating a few fields, this is the simplest fix to your situation:

```
function validate(nameId, branchId) {
  if (document.getElementById(nameId).value=="")
  {
             alert("Name Feild can not be blank");
             document.getElementById(nameId).focus();
             return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById(branchId).value=="SelectBranch")
  {
             alert("Branch Should Be Selected");
             document.getElementById(branchId).focus();
             return false;
  }
}
```

In your code-behind:

```
//Note your current method is deprecated after .Net 2.0+, should use this instead:
//ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("validation", "validation.js");
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript", "<script type='text/javascript' src='validation.js'></script>"); 
btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return validate('{0}','{1}')", tbName.ClientID, ddlBranch.ClientID));
```

Comment: @OP: You can move it to its own file if you make the IDs of the elements to validate parameters to the function, e.g., `function validate(nameId, branchId)` and then use `nameId` instead of `"<%=tbName.ClientID%>"` and `branchId` instead of `"<%=ddlBranch.ClientID%>"` (note that you no longer use the quotes; e.g. `document.getElementById(nameId).value`). Then script in your ASPX page can call the `validate` function in the external file like so: `validate("<%=tbName.ClientID%>", "<%=ddlBranch.ClientID%>")`.

Comment: @T.J. - +1 Good solution, as long as it's only a few fields that would be perfectly manageable.

Comment: @T.J. - Added to the answer so the formatting's easier to read - If you change your mind from a comment and post that answer yourself I'll remove, just @me so I know to!

Comment: Thank You for quick responce. But I am afrid to say that I still have the same error

Comment: @Nani - Can you post what your **rendered** html looks like?

Answer (score 1):

give the object you want to reference a html id which would output like

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

than you can reference it by

```
document.getElementById("myid")
```